# Moodle - update_moduleinfo - invalid course module id

Tags: plugins, moodle, moodle-api

I'm currently building a new moodle plugin. I'm using `add_moduleinfo` and `update_moduleinfo`. To add a new attandance atictivity in a course and update it later on.

Sadly I'm facing the issue that `update_moduleinfo` always throws an "**invalid course module id**" error. I already checked the cm entry in my database to ensure im using the right module instance.

I dont really know what to do.

```
            $cm = get_coursemodule_from_instance($moduleName, $activityID, $course->id);
            $moduleinfo = update_moduleinfo($cm, $moduleinfo, $course); <-- Error
```

Thats how I try to update the entry.

I also found that post. Didn't help anything.
[Moodle - Invalid course module ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438858/moodle-invalid-course-module-id)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue myself:

```php
$moduleinfo->introeditor['format'] = FORMAT_HTML;
$moduleinfo->introeditor['text'] = "INTRO TEXT";
$moduleinfo->coursemodule = $cm->id;

list($cm, $moduleinfo) = update_moduleinfo($cm, $moduleinfo, $course, null);
```

In order to use this function the above mentioned properties need to exist in order to perform a update.